# Install Service with custom credentials

Tags: windows, service, wix, installation

I have a Service to install by my installer. On UI user can choose to install this service as LocalSystem or with specified user credentials.
My Wix code looks like this:

```
<Component Id="C.MyService.exe" Guid="{Guid}">
        <File Id="MyService.exe" Name="MyService.exe" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes"
              Source="MyServicePath" />
        <ServiceInstall Id="MyServiceInstall" DisplayName="[SERVICE_NAME]" Account="[SERVICE_ACCOUNT]" Password="[SERVICE_PASSWORD]" Name="[SERVICE_NAME]" ErrorControl="normal" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Interactive="no">
        </ServiceInstall>
        <ServiceControl Id="MyServiceStart" Name="[SERVICE_NAME]" Start="install" Wait="no" />
        <ServiceControl Id="MyServiceStop" Name="[SERVICE_NAME]" Stop="both" Wait="yes" />
        <ServiceControl Id="MyServiceRemove" Name="[SERVICE_NAME]" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="SetStartServicePermission" Guid="{Guid}">
        <CreateFolder/>
        <Condition>NOT USE_LOCALSYSTEM_ACCOUNT</Condition>
        <util:User Id="ServiceUser" Name="[SERVICE_ACCOUNT]" Password="[SERVICE_PASSWORD]" CreateUser="no" LogonAsService="yes" UpdateIfExists="yes" />
      </Component>
```

When I choose LocalSystem, service installs and works fine. But with custom user credentials service installs, but fails to start with an error "Service ServiceName failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services". 
The custom user already exists and belong to Administrators group.
When I install with LocalSystem and change Log On credentials for service manually, it starts successlully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I have misprinted in ServicePassword property name and installer set empty password for service user.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness - I successfully used the following code to give LogonAsService permission:

```
<util:User Id="ProcessingServiceUser" Domain="[APP_USER_DOMAIN]" Name="[APP_USER_NAME]" Password="[APP_USER_PASSWORD]" CreateUser="no" LogonAsService='yes' UpdateIfExists='yes' />
```

So CreateUser should be 'no', but UpdateIfExists='yes'.

Though I think this is not your problem as you said that user already have this permission.

Is your installer launches with elevated permissions? What OS version do you install to? I suppose you created per-user installation so that it doesn't ask for elevated permissions but after that you are trying to start service. Try launching your MSI from administrative command-line (msiexec /i YourInstaller.msi) instead of double-clicking it.

Comment: >> Is your installer launches with elevated permissions?
Yes.

>> What OS version do you install to?
Windows 7, Windows 2008.

>> I suppose you created per-user installation so that it doesn't ask for elevated permissions but after that you are trying to start service.
I created per-machine installation.

>> Try launching your MSI from administrative command-line (msiexec /i YourInstaller.msi) instead of double-clicking it.
Result is the same.

Comment: Just one more idea - I'm not sure how installer will process start="install" in combination with stop="both". Try removing the element with stop attribute. Additionally, I use only one ServiceControl element with all atributes I need instead of 3. Sorry for asking again, but are you sure your console was administrative (title should be Administrator: Command Prompt) and not the regular-permissions one? Because I can't imagine the situation when installer has full permissions from the beginning and fails to start service.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure my installer have administrative privileges. With LocalSystem user the service starts successfully.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy do you also have code that checks if account is valid?

Comment: @juFo, No, I'm afraid I don't own that code anymore. But what do you mean under "valid" user? I had custom action to validate user when leaving wizard page with credentials entered.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy "valid" if user exists and credentials are valid. I've got it working but when users have a personal microsoft account and are not in a domain e.g. (username@outlook.com) then it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @juFo The idea with custom action should be the same. You just need to find out a method of validating credentials for user types you support. probably you currently implemented support of Active Directory users, but need to extend it with open Microsoft accounts or local computer accounts etc. It's a separate topic for question I think.

Answer (score 0):

You have the createuser attribute as false.  Therefore WiX isn't creating/updating the user to give the SeLogonAsService right.  When you go into Services.msc and enter the creds it implicitly does this for you and starts working.

Comment: In all forums threads abiut service user updatings the CreateUser attribute is false. I have an error "Failed to create user. (-2147022651 TestUser1)", if I set CreateUser as true. TestUser1 already exists and have RunAsService rights.